# Transparent Theme Crashes in Lollipop

Tags: android, themes, transparent

I want to use **transparent** **theme** in one of my **activities**

I have tried this :

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent"  parent="android:Theme">
     <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
     <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

it works fine in pre lollipop but in lollipop it doesn't work (force close)

then i have tried this one :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

it doesn't works in pre 21 and 21

so please help to fix this problem.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I have fixed this issue

I just set color primary - accent - and primary dark to this theme and it works perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Put in your layout

android:alpha="0.00"

It works

Comment: with Transparent Theme or Translucent?